# Example about about function has no upper and lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a function $f:[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which has no upper bound and lower bound.

Does the linear function $f(x) = \tan(x)$ work, and if so how?

Appreaciate any help with that.

Comment: $x \mapsto \tan(x)$ is not linear...

Comment: $\tan$ is in fact bounded on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: That gives you a good place to start, yes. You'll have to tweak it some to get an asymptote in the interval, and to make sure it is defined on the *whole* interval.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ cannot be continuous at every $x\in [0,1]$ you can just let $f(1/n)=n(-1)^n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ and let $f(x)$ be anything you want when $x\in [0,1]\setminus \{1/n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example $x\mapsto \frac{x}{(x-1)(x+1)}$ (you may set an arbitrary value at $1$ and $-1$ so that it's well-defined).

If you want to stick with $\tan$, consider $g:x\mapsto \frac{\pi}2 x$. Then $\tan \circ g$ with some additional values at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ fits the bill.